# Updating a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

At the moment I have two models

- Registrant `{email: string, password: string, availability: RegistrantAvailability, ...}`
- RegistrantAvailability `{unavailableDates: Date[], days: number[]}`

The RegistrantAvailability schema becomes a subdocument of the Registrant schema. The `days` property is an array of numbers between 0 and 6 (0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday) and converting these day numbers to a list of dates in that current week using the below:

```js
async dayNumberToDate(today: Date, dayNumber: number) {
    const dow = new Date(today).getDay();
    console.log(dow);
    const offset = dow - dayNumber
    
    const d = new Date(today)
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - offset);
    console.log(d);
    return d
  }
```

What I am stuck with is looping through each registrant and updating this `day` property with the current week dates returned from the previous function.

This is what I have tried

```js
const regDayDates = registrants.map(registrant => {
      return registrant.availability.days.map(day => {
        const newDay = this.dayNumberToDate(date, day)
        return newDay
      })
    });
```

At the moment the result is returning the below:

```js
[
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ]
]
```

Comment: Why is `dayNumberToDate` an async function? It doesn't do anything that's asynchronous.

Comment: Declaring it `async` makes it return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

First, change `dayNumberToDate()` to an ordinary function, there's no need for it to be `async`.

Second, you should be assigning the result of the inner `map` to the `Date` property.

Third, the outer `map` should be `forEach()`. You don't need a list of these results, you're doing this to modify the `RegistrantAvailability` object.

```js
const regDayDates = registrants.forEach(registrant =>
  registrant.availability.unavailableDates = registrant.availability.days.map(day =>
    this.dayNumberToDate(date, day)));
```

Comment: Thanks, only thing is that the registrant.Date property does not exist. it is only Registrant.Availability.day: number[] that I want to convert in this specific function to a date array

Comment: how will this work if the schema doesn't have a property called registrant.availability.Dates ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your model. The name of the property should be `registrant.availability.unavailableDates`.